# VB6 equivalent of string.IsNullOrEmpty

Tags: string, vb6

I'm doing some work on a legacy application, and my VB6 skills aren't that great. I need to check whether a String field has been initialized and set to something other than null/nothing or an empty string. In C# I'd just do something like:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(myObj.Str))
```

I'm not sure what the equivalent to this was in VB6, and I'm nervous about using `If myObj.Str = ""` and calling it good. What's the correct way to do this?

To clarify, I want something that will return True if any of the following are true:

- The field hasn't been initialized
- The field is an empty string (str = "", length = 0)
- The field is set to null, or Nothing, or vbnull, or whatever form of the null value applies to VB6 strings.

The field was originally a Long, and the code I'm replacing checked whether it was set to 0.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

VB6 was designed to be **easy**

Use

```
If str = "" Then 
  ' uninitialised, null or empty ""
```

- Strings are automatically initialized to [**edit**] a null string.
- The null string is vbNullString.
- But *don't worry* about null strings. A VB6 null string is indistinguishable from an empty string "" for (almost) any string manipulation.

Comment: Casting vbNullString to LPCSTR argument of an API function can be a problem.

Comment: @wqw True (but quite a rare situation). I will edit to say "almost any"

Comment: Incorrect. Strings are not automatically initialized to be empty. Using StrPtr(s) will return 0 for a null string(vbNullString) and StrPtr("") will return the address of the empty string. However, VB6 really does treat them both the same, it's only API calls that may care.

Comment: This is a trap when converting to VB.Net. In VB.Net vbNullstring<>String.Empty

Comment: @Kathy Thanks for pointing out that strings are initialised to null strings, I have edited accordingly. Interestingly enough the VB6 documentation says strings are initialised to an empty string, but I guess the fact that a null string is actually used is considered an implementation detail, as the VB6 designers strived to make null string indistinguishable from an empty string. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243352(v=VS.60).aspx) that

Comment: @Dabblernl Are you sure? My VB2008 gives `True` when I execute `Debug.Print(vbNullString = String.Empty)`

Answer (score 11):

The most optimized and safe way to meet your 3 requirements is as follows:

```
If LenB(myObj.Str) = 0 
Then Debug.Print "String is empty/null/not initialized" 
Else Debug.Print "Not Empty"
```

Comment: +1  Testing the Length of a string is indeed the most efficient/performant way to test a string for zero-length.

Comment: Testing the length is the most performant way to test a string for zero-length, but it is less readable than a simple `str = ""`. How often is the performance really important?

Answer (score 4):

use **Is Null** for stings or **is nothing** for objects

use **len**("*string*") instead of "*string*"="" because it is faster

```
Dim s As String

If Not (s Is Null) Then
  MsgBox "SET"

  if (len(s)>0) then
    MsgBox "size > 0"
  else
    MsgBox "size = 0"
  end if
Else
  MsgBox "not SET"
End If
```

regards

Comment: And for empty string use If LenB(s) = 0 Then

Comment: edit* ^ what he said. --he also wants to check for an initialized string that is empty or 0 length so also check for s == ""

Comment: Is Null for strings is incorrect in VB6 *or* VB.Net. Just use = "" for VB6 and in VB.Net use Is Nothing

Answer (score 4):

As 'Nulls' and 'Empty Strings' are actually different values, this approach can capture both for you easily:

```
If strValue & "" = "" Then
    'This is Null
Else
    'This is NOT Null
End If
```

Comment: `Trim(strValue & vbNullString) = vbNullString` will capture space-filled as well.

Comment: Incorrect. Nulls and empty strings are identical values in VB6 (and VB.Net).

Comment: That's a little weird, Ms Access 2000 - 2003 uses VB6 and it definately treats them as different values. Unless that is to do with the Jet aspect of the tables.

Answer (score 2):

I tried, `If str = ""` Then

but it did not work.

The best way to identify if the given string is null is:

`If IsNull(str)` Then

' This will work perfectly

Comment: But testing for null doesn't catch an empty string. So you have to do both.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding info to MarkJ's answer. If you are working with a recordset, this

```
if rs.fields.item("rsField").value = "" then
```

Will throw a runtime error in case that item is null. You should do this:

```
if rs.fields.item("rsField").value & "" = "" then
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

'Using VbNullstring can be a very effective way

```
Dim YourString as string  
dim HasValue as boolean

If YourString = vbnullstring then  
    HasValue = False  
Else  
HasValue = True  
End if
```

Comment: Don’t write code like this; write `HasValue = YourString <> vbNullString` instead: it’s more direct, the `If` is completely unnecessary here. Furthermore, there’s no reason to **ever** write this in VB6. You can simply say `HasValue = YourString <> ""`

Answer (score 0):

As an improvement to other answers:

This method should work even faster:

```
If Len(s) Then
'string not empty
Else
'string empty
End If
```