# How do I pass Form1.TextBox1.Text to Form2.TextBox2.Text using Visual Basic (correctly)?

Tags: vba, variables, transfer

This is a continuation of a question asked two years ago in this thread:
[VB6 equivalent of string.IsNullOrEmpty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762345/vb6-equivalent-of-string-isnullorempty)
(I think.) A programmer recommended I use the String.IsNullorEmpty method, which I used this thread for to convert to Visual Basic, but I still couldn't get it to work.

The specifics of my question are here, including all current code:
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/visual-basic-4-5-6/threads/473930/passing-data-between-forms-in-vba

Here is the gist of it, copied directly from the second link:
So I'm trying to make a link between TextBox1.Text on Form1 to TextBox2.Text on Form 2. What I currently have is a line of code underneath my TextBox2_Change code reading:
TextBox2 = Form1.TextBox1.Text

This ALMOST does what I want it to do. The only problem is that it is requiring me to input any character in to the TextBox2 when Form2 pops up before it displays.

I'm trying to get that problem solved and then I'm eventually going to try to get it to chop off part of the file name until just the project file name displays.......but that's a whole different game I'll be playing. One step at a time.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explanation

You should write the code under the `Form2_Load` event.

If you write the code under `Textbox2_TextChanged` event, the code will be executed only when you type or delete something in `Textbox2` (That is the same as Text being changed).

## Code and Example

```
Private Sub Form2_Load () Handles Mybase.Load
        Textbox2.Text = Form1.Textbox1.Text
End Sub
```

Hope it works perfectly!

Comment: Thanks so much! That makes a lot of sense to me. Only problem now is that it doesn't like that "Handles" command. I keep getting an error that it's an unexpected end of statement... But hopefully I can figure that out! Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to be of help! Please accept this answer by clicking on the green tick, if you are fully satisfied.

Comment: Done! Hopefully I can get it to understand the Handles command :) Thanks again.

Comment: Got it!

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Old_Name_Display.Text = Browser.TextBox1.Text

End Sub

The handles command was not needed :)

Comment: Yeah I didn't know that made a difference :) I'm very new to this. I got lucky and figured things out so far, including that with your guidance. You explanation made me understand what I was doing wrong, even if the syntax would not work. I can now rename a folder! Sadly I need to be able to rename hundreds of files at once instead....baby steps!

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you observe is normal : your TextBox2 is only updated (with the value from TextBox1) ... when you update it manually (**_Change**).

Comment: You disagree with @KashishArora then? There's not a way to make it auto-update?

Sorry guys, I'm very new to VB. I just started learning it on Friday for this work project.

Comment: No, he's doing it right, his explanation is just clearer than mine. I was saying that you put the code to change the content inside the code of the event handler triggered upon changing the content, kind of a snake biting its own tail situation (hoping that makes sense ?).

Comment: Yeah that makes a lot of sense! Hopefully I can get his method to work. It doesn't like this "handles" command one bit.

Answer (score -1):

Hey friend it very simple. you need not to add any kind of other functions just use dot(.) operator to access all components of Form1.
e.g.:
`Form1.TextBox1.AppendText("hello")`

or you can read value from Form2 and insert it into Form1.
e.g. :

```
Dim txt As String=TextBox1.Text
Form1.TextBox1.AppendText(txt)
```